# How to do Junit testing with mockito for service layer and Dao layer with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I have layered architecture in the spring boot project like Controller -> Service -> Dao. I have to write unit test cases to check all functionality. I want to write unit test cases for service layer and Dao layer. Service layer internally calls 3 DAO methods.

Currently, I am trying to write test cases for service layer and its internally calling Dao methods but its giving null pointer exception.

**My Testing code is as below. After executing this test case, I am getting null pointer exception on 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(existingUtQuery, namedParameters, GeneratorRowMapper)' in GeneratorRepository Dao class. I have initialized 'generatorRepository = new GeneratorRepository() and uTService = new UTService()' in Response1 test method of test class otherwise it give null pointer exception.**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class GenerationApplicationTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private GeneratorRepository generatorRepository;
    
    @Mock
    private  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private UTService uTService;
    
    
    @Test
    public void Response1() throws Exception {

        generatorRepository = new GeneratorRepository();
        uTService = new UTService();

        Request request = new Request("12345678", "F", 0, "A");
        Generator generator = new Generator("12345678.F","3er45FGTYH");

        System.out.println("utService  :  "+utService);

        when(generatorRepository.findExisting(request)).thenReturn(generator);
        Response response = uTService.getUT(Request);
        assertEquals("12345678.F", response.getValue());
        assertEquals("3er45FGTYH", response.getPre());
    }

}
```

Service Class

```
@Service
public class UTService {

    @Autowired
    private GeneratorRepository generatorDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TableFunctionRepository tableFunctionRepository;

    public Response getUT(Request request) throws UTNotFoundException {
        Response response = new Response();
        Generator existing = new Generator();
        TableFunction tableData = new TableFunction();
        Generator new = new Generator();
        Reasons exclusionInclusion = null;
        existing = generatorDAO.findExisting(request);
        if (existing != null) {
            response.setResponse(existing);
            return response;
        }
        tableData = tableFunctionRepository.callTableValuedFunction(request);
        if (tableData == null) {
            String exceptionMessage = Request + " not found in database";
            throw new UTNotFoundException(exceptionMessage);
        } else {
            new.setInfo(request.getId(), request.getSubId(), request.getRevisionNo(), request.getState());
            exclusionInclusion = checkExclusionInclusionCriteria(tableData);
            new.setExclusionInclusionReasonId(exclusionInclusion.getReasonCode());
            new = generateUT(tableData, exclusionInclusion, new);
            response.setResponse(new);
            generatorDAO.saveUT(new);
        }
        log.info("finished getUT");
        return response;

    }
    
}
```

Dao Classes

```
@Repository
public class GeneratorRepository 
{
    @Value("${sql.saveutiQuery}")
    private String saveUTQuery;

    @Value("${sql.existingUtiQuery}")
    private String existingUtQuery;


    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BeanPropertyRowMapper<Generator> generatorRowMapper;

    public int saveUT(Generator generator) {
        int rowsAffected = 0;
        try {
            SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(generator);
            rowsAffected = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(saveUTQuery, paramSource);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return rowsAffected;
    }

    public Generator findExistingUT(Request request) {
        Generator ut = new Generator();
        try {
            SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("No", request.getId(), Types.VARCHAR)
                    .addValue("Sub", request.getSubId(), Types.VARCHAR)
                    .addValue("Revision", request.getRevision(), Types.INTEGER)
                    .addValue("state", request.getState(), Types.VARCHAR);
            ut = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(existingUtQuery, namedParameters, GeneratorRowMapper);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return ut;
    }
}


@Repository
public class TableFunctionRepository {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BeanPropertyRowMapper<TableFunction> tableFunctionRowMapper;

    @Value("${sql.DetailsQuery}")
    private String tableDetailsQuery;

    public TableFunction callTableValuedFunction(Request request) {
        TableFunction tableDetails = new TableFunction();
        try {
            SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("No", request.getId(), Types.VARCHAR)
                    .addValue("Sub", request.getSub(), Types.VARCHAR)
                    .addValue("Revision", request.getRevision(), Types.INTEGER)
                    .addValue("state", request.getState(), Types.VARCHAR);

            tableDetails = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(tableDetailsQuery, namedParameters, tableFunctionRowMapper);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }       
        return tableDetails;
    }
}
```

**What approach should I follow to write test cases using junit and mockito to cover both service and Dao layer.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, When you have `@autowired` variables it means that you need to `@mock` them if you want to get mocked object.

Then if you test the Service class then you need to use `@InjectMocks` for this service. It means that you are creating a mocked service for testing and injecting to him all mocks that you mocked with `@mock` annotation or with another way.

Here updated version of your test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UTServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private UTService uTService;

    @Mock
    private GeneratorRepository generatorRepository;

    @Mock
    private TableFunctionRepository tableFunctionRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetUT_whenExistingGeneratorFound_returnResponse() throws UTNotFoundException {
        // Arrange
        Request request = new Request("12345678", "F", 0, "A");
        Generator existingGenerator = new Generator("12345678.F", "3er45FGTYH");
        Response expectedResponse = new Response(existingGenerator);

        // Mock generatorRepository to return an existing generator for the given request
        when(generatorRepository.findExisting(request)).thenReturn(existingGenerator);

        // Act
        Response actualResponse = uTService.getUT(request);

        // Assert
        assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse);
    }
```

And you can test your exception throwing

```
@Test
    public void testGetUT_whenTableDataNotFound_throwUTNotFoundException() throws UTNotFoundException {
        Request request = new Request("12345678", "F", 0, "A");
        when(tableFunctionRepository.callTableValuedFunction(request)).thenReturn(null);

        assertThrows(UTNotFoundException.class, () -> uTService.getUT(request));
    }
```

Also, you can test the one more case when all is passing by adding this lines to first test case but write 3rd test for it:

```
 when(generatorRepository.findExisting(request)).thenReturn(null);

        // Mock tableFunctionRepository to return tableData for the given request
        when(tableFunctionRepository.callTableValuedFunction(request)).thenReturn(tableData);

        // Mock the generateUT method to return the expectedGenerator
        when(uTService.generateUT(tableData, exclusionInclusion, any(Generator.class)))
```

Comment: your answer is really very helpful. Thanks a lot !!